# Logging memory/CPU usage over time?

Tags: plotting

Can one use Mathemematica to target some currently running (Linux) application, say with `pid`, and to plot (say `ListLinePlot`?) its memory/CPU usage over time?

Comment: You might be interested in e.g. [`OpenRead`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OpenRead.html) and [`ReadLine`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReadLine.html) to open and read from a pipe generated by `pid`. Honestly I would guess that there might be simpler pre-built system monitoring tools that can do the data acquisition and plotting for you, rather than re-inventing the wheel in MMA. If you are set on doing it this way, though, you will want to provide more details: what format does `pid` return? what timing are you thinking of? etc etc.

Comment: I have an answer that provides a real-time plot of the memory usage (obtained by reading the /proc/pid/status file for the value of VmRSS) and the CPU usage (from the linux "top -b -n1 -p pid" command).  The answer uses an `Overlay` of 2 `Dynamic` plots having different y-axis scales on the left and right.  If anyone is interested, let me know when this question is re-opened.

Comment: LouisB: I'm interested!